# Match type errors between IO Char and [Char]

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to get input from user and print out depending on input (code modified from [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html)):

```
import Data.Char (toUpper)

isGreen = do
    putStrLn "Is green your favorite color?"
    inpStr <- getLine
    if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then "YES" else "NO"
    -- following also does not work: 
    -- if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then return "YES" else return "NO" 

main = do
    print isGreen
```

However, I am getting many errors:

```
testing.hs:7:44: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO Char
        Actual type: [Char]
    • In the expression: "YES"
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then "YES" else "NO"
      In the expression:
        do { putStrLn "Is green your favorite color?";
             inpStr <- getLine;
             if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then "YES" else "NO" }

testing.hs:7:55: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO Char
        Actual type: [Char]
    • In the expression: "NO"
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then "YES" else "NO"
      In the expression:
        do { putStrLn "Is green your favorite color?";
             inpStr <- getLine;
             if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then "YES" else "NO" }

testing.hs:12:5: error:
    • No instance for (Show (IO Char)) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print isGreen
      In the expression: do { print isGreen }
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { print isGreen }
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is, essentially, confusing `IO` code with non-IO, or "pure" code.

In `isGreen`, you have a `do` block involving `putStrLn` and `getLine`. This means the function must return a value of some type `IO a`. You can't get a "plain string" from it, which seems to be your intention. The final line of the `do` block must be a monadic value, in this case an `IO` value - so you can't simply have a string here.

However, you can use the `return` function to make an `IO String` out of a `String`, as in the commented out code that "also does not work":

```
if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then return "YES" else return "NO"
```

This works fine, and is necessary, as far as `isGreen` is concerned. The error comes because of what happens in `main`. You cannot `print` an `IO` value - an `IO String` is not actually a string, it's basically a "promise" of a future string, that will only materialise at runtime based on (in this case) the user's input.

But since `main` is an `IO` action anyway, this isn't a problem. Just do this instead:

```
main = do
    isItGreen <- isGreen
    print isItGreen
```

or, completely equivalently, but imo more succinctly,

```
main = isGreen >>= print
```

You might prefer `putStrLn` to `print`, which when printing a string will include the enclosing quotes.

Note that, if you had included a type signature for each top level value (here `isGreen` and `main`), you'd have got more useful information from the compiler as to where the errors were.

Comment: The flipped version, `print =<< isGreen`, corresponds more directly to the typical right-to-left data flow order in Haskell—cf. `.`, `$`, `<$>`, `<*>`

Answer (score 5):

`isGreen` uses `IO`, so the type needs to be `IO String`, not `String`. It is an IO action that can *produce* a string, not a string itself.

```
isGreen :: IO String
isGreen = do
    putStrLn "Is green your favorite color?"
    inpStr <- getLine
    return $ if (toUpper (head inpStr) == 'Y') then "YES" else "NO"
```

Likewise, `print` expects a `String`, not an `IO String`, so you need to use the `IO` monad instance. (Actually, you should use `putStrLn`, since you don't need the implicit `show` that `print` will use.)

```
main = isGreen >>= putStrLn
```

Here, `>>=` is creating a *new* `IO` action which will execute the `IO` action on the left (`isGreen`), and pass the value produced to the function on the right (`putStrLn`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is Haskell so particular about this seemingly small difference in type (`IO String` vs `String`)?

Comment: Haskell only allows pure functions, so `getLine` cannot be a function; instead  it is a *value*  called an IO action. Each time the action is *executed*, it can produce a new value, but *you*, the Haskell programmer, cannot execute it. Only the runtime can execute an IO action, so the most you can do is *compose* IO actions to produce one you ultimately want execute.

Comment: In a nutshell, though, the idea is `isGreen >>= putStrLn` creates an IO action that takes `putStrLn` as a "callback". You can't execute `isGreen`, but `>>=` effectively says: "Once you execute `isGreen` to produce a `String`, please call `putStrLn` on that `String`.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to provide *referential transparency*; you never have to "simulate" your code to reason about what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Since `isGreen` here is an `IO a`, you can not use `if … then … else …` as last line. You need to return an `IO a`.

You can however use `pure` here (or `return`, although there is nothing inherently wrong with that, it ):

```
import Data.Char(toUpper)

isGreen :: IO String
isGreen = do
    putStrLn "Is green your favorite color?"
    inpStr <- getLine
    pure (if "Y" == take 1 (map toUpper inpStr) then "YES" else "NO")
```

Here `"Y" == take 1 (map toUpper inpStr)` is more safe, since if the user has written an empty line, then `head` will error on the empty list.

Since `isGreen` has type `IO String`, then you can not use `print isGreen`, you here can use *bind* `(>>=)`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = isGreen >>= print
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why can't compiler ignore `IO` part of `IO a` and proceed?

Comment: @mso: there is a fundamental difference between an `IO a` and an `a`. In some papers it is written as "Monads as nuclear waste containers" :). In fact, a compiler does not need to know at all about `IO`, it is just a type constructor. The type systems says that `a` and `IO a` are different, so that is basically it.

Comment: "Monads as nuclear waste containers" is very interesting. Is it mentioned in a positive or negative sense? Are monads very useful or very dangerous? I believe they must be very useful as protecting from error prone code.

Comment: @rnso: very useful. Haskell is one of the few languages that makes destinction between all sorts of side-effects, and for such side effects uses monads (as a container) to prevent it from "infecting" the rest of the program.

Comment: @rnso In most languages, when `f()` has type "integer", the expression `f() + f()` can evaluate to an odd integer, thanks to side effects (e.g. asking the user for input). In Haskell, if `f () :: Int`, then `f () + f ()` must have exactly the same semantics of `2 * f ()`, so it has to be even (if it terminates). Performance might differ, but the results are the same. If instead `f () :: IO Int`, then we allow side effects again, and summing can result in an odd number again. We write the sum as `(+) <$> f () <*> f ()`, in this case, resulting in type `IO Int` because of the side effects.