# How to plug this type hole 2

Tags: haskell

Following along from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032008/how-to-plug-this-type-hole/58032339#58032339) (I've refactored the code from main into its own function) I am trying to get the following code to compile:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.PDF.Info

title :: FilePath -> String
title path = do
  result <- pdfInfo path
  case result of
    Left someError -> do
      return "no title"
    Right info -> do
      case (pdfInfoTitle info) of
        Nothing -> return "no title"
        Just title -> return (T.unpack title)
```

I am getting

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: return "no title"
      In the expression: do return "no title"
      In a case alternative: Left someError -> do return "no title"
   |
14 |       return "no title"
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To me it looks like I am returning a String ([Char]) type, but I guess not. Guidance please, thanks in advance.

Here it is in greater context of what I hope to accomplish:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Data.List (isSubsequenceOf, isSuffixOf)
import System.Directory (listDirectory)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.PDF.Info

title :: FilePath -> String
title path = do
  result <- pdfInfo path
  case result of
    Left someError -> do
      return "no title"
    Right info -> do
      case (pdfInfoTitle info) of
        Nothing -> return "no title"
        Just title -> return (T.unpack title)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print =<<
    liftM
      (filter
         (\path ->
            ((isSubsequenceOf "annotated" path) ||
             (isSubsequenceOf "annotated" (title path))) &&
            (isSuffixOf "pdf" path)))
      (listDirectory "/home/foo")
```

Comment: `return` is not a keyword like in a lot of imperative languages. `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` is a function. So here it makes your function a `Monad m => m String`. This is already the case because you use `do`.

Comment: In addition to what @WillemVanOnsem, the `pdfInfo` function does IO, so there is "no escape" from that back to pure code. So no function that uses it, as yours does, can return a "plain" `String`, or any other type that doesn't involve `IO`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, ah, that really helps. Not sure how to salvage what I have...

Comment: @Joe just make your function return an `IO String` rather than a `String`. I believe in that case you can simply leave the function body alone, but I haven't checked in detail. Then in `main` you can "assign" to the result of `title` by doing something like `x <- title path` and using the string `x` in subsequent code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match type errors between IO Char and \[Char\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976753/match-type-errors-between-io-char-and-char)

Comment: @RobinZigmond, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me it looks like I am returning a `String` (`[Char]`) type.

**No**. `return` is not, as in most imperative languages, a keyword to return content. It is a function. Indeed [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) is a function that "*injects a value in a monadic type*".

The `pdfInfo` function has as type [**`pdfInfo :: MonadIO m => FilePath -> m (Either PDFInfoError PDFInfo)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pdfinfo-1.5.4/docs/Text-PDF-Info.html#v:pdfInfo). So we will need to use a `MonadIO` type:

```
title :: MonadIO m => FilePath -> m String
title path = do
    result <- pdfInfoTitle info
    case pdfInfo path of
        Left someError -> return "no title"
        Right info -> case (pdfInfoTitle info) of
            Nothing -> return "no title"
            Just title -> return (T.unpack title)
```

We here thus return an `m String`. You can see a `MonadIO` as a "recipe" to construct a value (here a `String`). Not a `String` itself.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. Now I am looking to get the do syntax correct for `x <- title path` in the lambda for `filter`...

Comment: @Joe, but you can not use `x <- title path` in a lambda (for `filter`). You could use `filterM`, but then you still can not use this since this is supposed to return a `Bool`. I would strongly advice taking a look what the difference between an `IO a` and `a` is, since it will otherwise make it very hard to solve the problem you aim to fix.

Comment: Next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037008/how-to-plug-this-type-hole-3