# How to plug this type hole 3

Tags: haskell

Following on from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035216/how-to-plug-this-type-hole-2), I am now able to get the desired result I was after, but in a totally evil way: using `unsafePerformIO`. I understand this is not the right way to approach this (though to my defense I got the idea from hoogle checking types, and then from an ag search in kmett's repos to see when he used `unsafePerformIO` across a hundred or so repos. I read the warnings on hackage, I know it is bad.).

What I'd like now is to be a way to do this without `unsafePerformIO`.

Here is the code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Data.List (isSubsequenceOf)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import System.Directory (listDirectory)
import System.FilePath ((</>), takeExtension)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import Text.PDF.Info

title :: FilePath -> IO String
title path = do
  result <- pdfInfo path
  case result of
    Left someError -> do
      return "no title"
    Right info -> do
      case (pdfInfoTitle info) of
        Nothing -> return "no title"
        Just title -> return (T.unpack title)

titleString :: FilePath -> String
titleString s = unsafePerformIO (title s)
{-# NOINLINE titleString #-}

dir = "/some/path"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print =<<
    liftM
      (filter
         (\path ->
            (isSubsequenceOf "annotated" (titleString (dir </> path))) &&
            (takeExtension path == ".pdf")))
      (listDirectory dir)
```

Along the way I tried to use hole typing and lots of Hoogle to get help from the tools (teach a man to fish..). I need mentoring to get the process of discovery using tools and docs more dialed. If you have tips on how you approach such things, or at least imagine what you would do if you lost all your long term memory of Haskell except hole typing and hoogle and let me know how you would proceed. I plan to watch Brian McKenna's data61 videos soon, but until then. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your opening paragraph reminds me of a famous koan in the go world: one time a beginner was reviewing one of his games with his teacher. The teacher stopped him at one point and said, "You must not play this move.". He said, "But it is joseki [a standard opening that all agree is good for both players]. I have seen many pros play this move.". The teacher replied, "When the pros play it, it is a good move. But when you play it, it is a mistake.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's split out your filtering function:

```
isAnnotatedPdf :: FilePath -> Bool
isAnnotatedPdf path = (isSubsequenceOf "annotated" (titleString (dir </> path))) && (takeExtension path == ".pdf")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print =<<
    liftM
      (filter isAnnotatedPdf)
      (listDirectory dir)
```

Now, use some syntactic sugar to clean up `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  dirList <- listDirectory dir
  let filteredList = filter isAnnotatedPdf dirList
  print filteredList
```

Next, change `isAnnotatedPdf` to return its result inside of `IO`, and then modify `main` so that it's okay to do that:

```
isAnnotatedPdf :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isAnnotatedPdf path = do
  return $ (isSubsequenceOf "annotated" (titleString (dir </> path))) && (takeExtension path == ".pdf")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  dirList <- listDirectory dir
  filteredList <- filterM isAnnotatedPdf dirList
  print filteredList
```

Extract a variable `pdfTitle` inside `isAnnotatedPdf` to make the next step more clear:

```
isAnnotatedPdf :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isAnnotatedPdf path = do
  let pdfTitle = titleString (dir </> path)
  return $ (isSubsequenceOf "annotated" pdfTitle) && (takeExtension path == ".pdf")
```

Finally, change `isAnnotatedPdf` to use its new `IO` context instead of using your `unsafePerformIO` wrapper:

```
isAnnotatedPdf :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isAnnotatedPdf path = do
  pdfTitle <- title (dir </> path)
  return $ (isSubsequenceOf "annotated" pdfTitle) && (takeExtension path == ".pdf")
```

And you're done! Now you can get rid of `titleString` and all of your references to `unsafePerformIO`.

---

As a bonus, you can now easily avoid the need to call `pdfInfo` on things that aren't PDFs, by moving the pure `takeExtension` check to before the monadic title check, like this:

```
isAnnotatedPdf :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isAnnotatedPdf path = if takeExtension path == ".pdf"
  then do
    pdfTitle <- title (dir </> path)
    return $ isSubsequenceOf "annotated" pdfTitle
  else return False
```

Or using `<$>` instead of `do`:

```
isAnnotatedPdf :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isAnnotatedPdf path = if takeExtension path == ".pdf"
  then isSubsequenceOf "annotated" <$> title (dir </> path)
  else return False
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I like the use of fmap at the end there, I was experimenting with that. Going inside the Monad with a Functor - just a tidbit I learned but wasn't experienced/knowledgeable enough yet to apply. This all really helps, thanks again.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Not only does it show the right way to do it, it lays out a mechanical process that people can apply to other, similar chunks of code: convert the pure version to `let foo = bar in baz` form, where `bar` is the thing that needs to become `IO`y instead of pure, then refactor to `do { foo <- bar; baz }` while changing `bar` to do `IO`. Even if `filterM` didn't exist, it could be created out of the source of `filter` by following this exact same process.